# How to mock a React Component in the __mocks__ directory with jest?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I have been trying to extract a common mocked component to the **mocks** folder without success. I am only able to do it with regular JS files, but not with Components.

If I have a module getList as so:

```
    export const getBigger = (a, b) => {
       return a >= b ? a : b;
    };
```

I can use it inside my component as so:

```
export default function App() {
  const bigger = getBigger("a", "b");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Bigger bigger={bigger} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I can put the pure js function inside the **mocks** folder

```
export const getBigger = jest.fn((p1, p2) => false);
```

And I can import it in my test without any problems:

```
import { getBigger as mockedGetBigger } from '../utils';
jest.mock('../utils');
```

And do my assertions:

```
expect(mockedGetBigger).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(mockedGetBigger).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a', 'b');
```

But I can't do the same if I want to mock the Bigger Component, it only works as so:

```
jest.mock('../Bigger', () => ({
   Bigger: jest.fn(() => <>Mocked Bigger Component</>),
}));
```

But if I extract the function to the **mocks** folder and I try to use it just as the simple js function I get an error:

```
import React from 'react';
export const Bigger = jest.fn(() => <>Mocked Bigger Image</>);
```

And in the test import it and use it as:

```
import { Bigger as MockedBigger } from '../Bigger';
jest.mock('../Bigger');
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught [Error: Bigger(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.]
```

I am not sure what the difference is when jest is importing and mocking in the same step or going to look for the mock function to the **mocks** folder.

Any ideas?
Somebody else complained about it here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6935

I made a simple codesandbox to help to understand the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/mocks-folder-example-oxht3?file=/src/index.js

And here is the guide from jest to put your mocks in the `__mocks__` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found out.

I created a CodeSandbox but as it happens, `jest.mock()` is not available in CodeSandbox yet...

Anyway my problem was that I was not using the same extension for the real file and its corresponding file in the `__mocks__` folder.

Silliest mistake ever!